# Getting active tab and generating confirm window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to develop extension that gets active tab and generate confirm window at current open tab. But I cannot do this with "window.confirm" because window is not defined. Here's my code:

**BACKGROUND.JS**

```
var notifyTimer = setInterval(func,5*1000);
  console.log('setinterval ran');

  
  function func(){ 
  let ActiveTab = getCurrentTab();
  console.log(ActiveTab)

}

async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  console.log(tab.url)
  //alert(" Hello!")
  // SOME CODE TO GENERATE CONFIRM WINDOW or ALERT
  return tab;
}
```

Currently it's fetching current active tab but I don't know how to generate confirm window

Kindly help me to generate alert with this code.

Comment: If you're using manifest V3, the background doesn't have a DOM, so you can't use alert() on it.

Comment: well, yes I'm using manifest version 3 and window is not defined there. what could be the possible solution to generate alert or confirm window at active tab?

Comment: with [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) document, you can

Comment: You can also use chrome.windows.create

Comment: @Robbi, Since `offscreen` is invisible, it is not a substitute for `alert`.

Comment: Well, currently I have implemented it by creating content.js and sending message to active tab. On receiving message, if statement checks the message and generates confirm window. And its working. :)

Comment: but here comes another issue. after first 5 seconds it generates error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." and then after 5 seconds content.js is ready and generates confirm window. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you can solve it with my answer.

Comment: @Norio Yamamoto : What I meant is open confirm popup inside a offscreen document.
I'm already doing it in an extension of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions":[
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
var notifyTimer = setInterval(func, 5 * 1000);
console.log('setinterval ran');


function func() {
  let ActiveTab = getCurrentTab();
  console.log(ActiveTab)

}

const alert = () => {
  alert(" Hello!");
}

async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  console.log(tab.url)
  //alert(" Hello!")
  // SOME CODE TO GENERATE CONFIRM WINDOW or ALERT
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: alert
  });

  return tab;
}
```

Comment: Can you help me if I want to open html page from my alert function on a new tab because window.open("example.html") or window.location.href="example.html" are not working.

Comment: what if I modify alert function to this:                                                                   
  const alert = () => {
   let result = confirm("Would you like to open html file");
   if (result == true){
     //open html page available in my local environment like example.html
  }
   return result;
}